# What happens if a receiver is beyond the end zone in football?

Tags: rules, american-football

I suspect that this is just "out of bounds", but what happens when a receiver catches a pass and has two feet out of the end zone at the far end? Is this just out of bounds or is there more forgiveness in the end zone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What happens if a receiver is beyond the end zone in football? I suspect that this is just "out of bounds"

Your suspicions are accurate.

> What happens when a receiver catches a pass and has two feet out of the end zone at the far end?

A player who catches a pass and has two feet out of the end zone at the far end had either touched a boundary line or touched outside a boundary line, and thus, is out of bounds.

---

Rule 3, Section 22, Article 1 in the [NFL Rule Book](http://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/image/rulebook/pdfs/2013%20-%20Rule%20Book.pdf) addresses this (emphasis mine).

> A player or an Official **is Out of Bounds when he touches**:
>
> (a) **A boundary line**; or
>
> (b) **Anything** other than a player, an official, or a pylon on or **outside a boundary line.**

---

Rule 2, Section 12, Article 4 in the [NCAA Football Rule Book](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/FR14.pdf) addresses this (in a clearer fashion, in my opinion).

> **Boundary Lines**
>
> ARTICLE 4. The boundary lines are the sidelines and the
>   end lines. The area enclosed by the boundary lines is “in bounds,’’
>   and the area surrounding and including the boundary lines is “out of
>   bounds.’’

Answer (score 6):

edmastermind29's answer is correct, save an exception.

If a receiver catches the ball but is carried out by a defender before he can land both feet inbounds, the pass is complete.

Rule 8, Section 1, Article 3, Item 6 in the [NFL Rule Book](http://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/image/rulebook/pdfs/11_2013_ForwardPass_BackPass_Fumble.pdf) addresses this.

> **Carried Out of Bounds:** If a player, who is in possession of the ball, is held up and carried out of bounds by an 
>   opponent before both feet or any part of his body other than his hands touches the ground inbounds, it is a completed 
>   or intercepted pass.

NCAA (college) rules are slightly different--the player needs only one foot to make contact inbounds for the completion.

Rule 2, Section 4, Article 1 of the [NCAA Football Rulebook](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/FR14.pdf):

> **Player Possession:** The ball is in player possession when a player has the ball firmly in his grasp
>   by holding or controlling it while contacting the ground inbounds.

Regarding the **Carried Out of Bounds** rule from the NFL, I could not find any references that suggests this also applies in college.

Comment: There is a distinction between "carried" and "pushed".  If a receiver is pushed out before he can get his feet in bounds, the pass is incomplete.  If he is carried by a defender out of bounds then the pass is complete.  The push rule is relatively new.  A push out used to be considered a completion.

Comment: @diggers3 wasn't pushing out a completion at one point, before the rule changed?

Comment: Also, let's not lose sight of the question of, "what happens when a receiver catches a pass and has two feet out of the end zone at the far end?" The initial answer to address the exception was fine, but the added detail is going off tangent.

Comment: @edmastermind29 agreed, thats why I wouldn't add it to an answer, but sometimes it is nice to expand on things, especially rules.  There are many little things within the rules that someone else may be wondering about.

Comment: @diggers3 While not explicitly stated in the rulebook, the [NFL's Rules Digest](http://www.nfl.com/rulebook/forwardpass) states `If a receiver would have landed inbounds with both feet but is carried or pushed out of bounds while maintaining possession of the ball, pass is complete at the out-of-bounds spot.` My NCAA edits were included for just the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @TrevorD I see the rules digest, but the force out rule was changed in 2008.  I don't know why the digest doesn't seem to have been updated. [NFL Rule Changes 2008](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/09000d5d809f6279/article/new-nfl-rules-for-2008)  The rule only applies to literally carrying someone, not pushing (or forcing) them out of bounds. [Breif explanation of the rule change](http://www.arrowheadpride.com/2008/4/2/16112/65451)

Comment: I've never heard about this "carry" clause until now.  If a receiver catches the ball while in the air in the end zone, it seems it'd be much easier for a defender to push him out of bounds.  I don't know why a defender would ever try to catch him and carry him out of bounds.

Comment: @pacoverflow If he's 10 yards from the boundary, it'd be a lot easier to carry him than to push him.

Comment: @Rawling how feasible or reasonable is that?

Comment: @edmastermind29 No idea how feasible - carrying an opposition player does occasionally happen in rugby, but maybe not 10 yards. It was just what popped into my head in response to "why would they even *have* that rule?"

Comment: @Rawling Right. It's heads up thinking, but it does not seem to be practical in a general sense.

Comment: @edmastermind29 [Some more discussion](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/blog/?p=197) *"In college, where they don't have a similar rule, wide receivers have been carried out of bounds occasionally when two defenders who were trying to cover them simply caught them while they were in the air."* ... *"the rule shows a willingness to delve into speculative matters to ensure fairness. It's about fault; if the receiver clearly makes the catch and clearly would have landed in-bounds, then he shouldn't be penalized because of something out of his control"*

Comment: @Rawling After watching [this play](https://nesncom.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/jimmy-graham.gif?w=600&h=331), would have it been "a lot easier" to carry him out of bounds, considering he is 10 yards from the boundary and there are two plus defenders around him?

Comment: @edmastermind29 Easier to catch and carry him than to push him from there, yes.

Comment: @Rawling The point I was trying to make is that I would think the player who catches the ball would squirm enough such that the defenders carrying him would have an (already) arduous task doing so. To the contrary, it would take one gigantic push to force him out of bounds from 10 yards away.